# Extracting data from over a million records

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have an Excel file in which I have set up a connection with an Access database. In the Excel file I have a list of names in column A, and I want to search these names in the Access database and return back two fields from that database. I need to do this for around 200-300 names.

Here is my code:

```vb
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "file.accdb"
Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strDB

For i = 2 To N

    Dim rstTable As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rstTable = New ADODB.Recordset
    lookup = Range("A" & i).Value


    strSQL = "SELECT NAME1,NAME2 FROM DATA WHERE [Field2]= """ & lookup & """;"
    'Store query output
    rstTable.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=objConnection
    'Paste results to Transactions sheet
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).CopyFromRecordset rstTable

    'Close the record set & connection
    rstTable.Close
    objConnection.Close
Next i
```

This works (kindof) but it takes an extremely long time and randomly crashes. Any ideas how to improve this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By "randomly crashes", I suppose you mean "randomly times out"? Do you have an index on `[Field2]`?

Comment: When you say it "crashes", do you mean it is not responding for a while? It is not the same. If your code works but takes a long time to run (Not Responding), it is not the same that if it does not and crashes. If there is not real problem to fix but you are looking for efficiency improvment, ask your question in [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: How much is 'N' ? You seem to make a lot of queries with results overlapping each other (except for te first row)

Comment: N is 202, by crashes I mean it stops responding for over an hour and I have to reset it. It works for 10 or so cases

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes, I've just called it [Field2] for a test run

Comment: It would certainly work more efficiently if you build a proper `WHERE` close using `IN (list of N values)` that would scan the table only once.

Comment: @iDevlop with 202 values I'd consider inserting them in an actual table and returning an inner join, given OP is looking for *exact* content and not a `LIKE` search. But yeah for a handful of values an `IN` clause would be good.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The question is about scanning a 1 million records table ONCE or 200 times. I'd bet my suggestion (and pcw's answer) is 200 times faster

Answer (score 0):

Making sure there is a key on the lookup field will help. I would suggest making a copy of the workbook and test external data from Access or MS Query to see if that gives a performance gain over VBA.

When using MS Query or data from Access, you can modify the command text in the connection properties and use ? in the where clause to specify the parameter in the worksheet (so you don't lose that functionality).

Answer (score 0):

I modified your SQL statement.  Replace the `Where [Field2] = "xxx"` by `Where [Field2] IN ("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")`.

```
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "file.accdb"
Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strDB

For i = 2 To N
    lookup = lookup & "'" & Range("A" & i).Value & "', "
Next i
lookup = left(lookup, len(lookup) - 2)

Dim rstTable As ADODB.Recordset
Set rstTable = New ADODB.Recordset

strSQL = "SELECT NAME1,NAME2 FROM DATA WHERE [Field2] IN (" & lookup & ");"
'Store query output
rstTable.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=objConnection
'Paste results to Transactions sheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).CopyFromRecordset rstTable

'Close the record set & connection
rstTable.Close
objConnection.Close
```

Comment: So have you turned lookup into an array?

Comment: No, not an array but a string.

Comment: The problem here is when I try to paste it back to excel, I need it to paste the records according to the name - I don't see how this code is doing that (i.e. the worksheets.range("B" & i) part)

Comment: Add the name in your SQL statement, something like  `"SELECT [Field2], NAME1,NAME2 FROM DATA WHERE [Field2] IN (" & lookup & ");" `.

Answer (score 0):

You close the connection after the first iteration, so your next iteration -- which does not have code to open the connection -- would fail. So you should move the `objConnection.Close` out of the loop.

But, even then, to execute the same kind of query over and over again, just with a different argument, can be done in one go, using the `IN (...)` syntax:

```vb
' Declare all your variables
Dim N As Long
Dim strDB As String
Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim rstTable As ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strDB = ThisWorkbook.Path & "file.accdb"
Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & strDB

' collect the values in comma-separated string
lookup = ""
For i = 2 To N
    lookup = lookup & ",""" & Range("A" & i).Value & """"
Next i
' Chop off the first comma
lookup = Mid(lookup, 2)

' Perform a single query, but also select the Field2 value
Set rstTable = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL = "SELECT Field2, NAME1,NAME2 FROM DATA WHERE [Field2] IN (" & lookup & ");"
' query output 
rstTable.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=objConnection

' Retrieve values 
While Not rstTable.EOF
    lookup = rstTable.Fields(0).Value
    ' Locate in which row to put the result
    For i = 2 To N
        If lookup = Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Range("B" & i).Value = rstTable.Fields(1).Value
            Range("C" & i).Value = rstTable.Fields(2).Value
        End If
    Next i
    rstTable.MoveNext
Loop    

' Close the record set & connection
rstTable.Close
objConnection.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you described, but I think it's far more efficient to do this in Access itself.  Just create a table with your names and do an Inner Join to the table you want to find 2 fields.  Should take less than a minute, and probably less than 30 seconds.